# how to inflate different layouts in Firebase Recycler Adapter

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, chat, layout-inflater

I have a chat activity and trying to inflate different layouts for the sender and receiver. so far I can retrieve data for the firebase realtime database but sender and receiver have the same layout, I have created layout second layout and tried with `viewType` but can't figure out how to assign the current user to a cretin layout, please help :(

chat activity

```
if (!employee)
    {



   FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessageModel>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("client_emp_messages")
                        .child(formattedDate+uid), ChatMessageModel.class)
                .build();

    }

    else
    {
        // employee
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String d = bundle.getString("path_to_client_realtime_db");


        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessageModel>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("client_emp_messages")
                        .child(d), ChatMessageModel.class)
                .build();


    }

    adapter = new ChatAdapter(options);
    nMessageList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

chat adapter

```
    public class ChatAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessageModel, ChatAdapter.ChatViewHolder>
    {
 

   public ChatAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessageModel> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull ChatMessageModel model) {
            holder.nMessage_text_view.setText(model.getMessage());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false);
            return new ChatViewHolder(view);


    }

    class ChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView  nMessage_text_view;

        public ChatViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nMessage_text_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text_view);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you is to make one layout. like the sender on the right side and receiver on the left side. you can use it with the help of a linear layout or relative layout. and set their visibility Invisible.
So download the message data from the database and check it by user id token. If it data matches with the current user token then display it in the right column and set visibility Visible and vice versa.

For that, you just need to store the user token with the message in the database.

Hope you understand it. Thanks

Comment: I am trying this idea with user ID but I dont think I know how to do it correctly because the entire chat get 1layout either sender or receiver :(